# Sufficient Boundary Condition to a General PDE on a General Domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

We know that for an ODE of $n^{th}$  order we need $n$ different boundary conditions. In PDEs, for example, for Laplace equation $\nabla^2 U=0$ (which is a second order PDE) we need only one B.C. (e.g Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions on the boundary $\partial \Omega$.)

$\large {\frac{\partial U}{\partial \vec n}|_{\partial \Omega}=0\space}$
or 
$\large  {   \space U|_{\partial \Omega}=0}$

I would like to know what is a sufficient boundary condition to a more general equation like $\Large {\frac{\partial^m U}{\partial x^m}+\frac{\partial^n U}{\partial y^n}=0}$ on a boundary $\partial  \Omega$. How do we know if a given boundary condition is sufficient to solve a general PDE? What is the relation between the order of a PDE and the number and type of boundary conditions needed on $\partial \Omega$.

Thanks.